# Template Parse Erros Angular "<" (" with Django REST framework

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to create a DRF API with an Angular front end for an existing project that I have.  I've created a serializer for User and Device.  I tried removing multiple pieces of the HTML component, managing to result in a different error, StaticInjectorError(AppModule -> DevicePostService).

I'm still pretty new to Angular so what it seems like the error is coming from is the fact that my devicepostservice is not getting served to the web page for some reason.

Console error:

```
[Error] Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "<" ("
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button
  [ERROR ->]</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.non_field_errors""): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@15:2
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button
  [ERROR ->]</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.non_field_errors""): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@15:2
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (" <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.non_field_errors">{{ error }}<br /></span>
  </div>
[ERROR ->]</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="_userService.token">
  <div class="col-sm-12">You are logged in as {{ "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@19:0
    _preparseLoadedTemplate (vendor.js:24658)
    normalizeTemplate (vendor.js:24635)
    loadDirectiveMetadata (vendor.js:26827)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:34471)
    forEach
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:34470)
    forEach
    _loadModules (vendor.js:34467:83)
    _compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js:34445)
    compileModuleAsync (vendor.js:34405)
    bootstrapModule (vendor.js:53721)
    ./src/main.ts (main.js:326:116)
    __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
    (anonymous function) (main.js:339)
    __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:79)
    checkDeferredModules (runtime.js:46)
    webpackJsonpCallback (runtime.js:33)
    Global Code (main.js:1)
```

App.component.html

```
<h2>Log In</h2>
<div class="row" *ngIf="!_userService.token">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Username:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="login-username" [(ngModel)]="user.username">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.username"><br />
    {{ error }}</span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label>Password:</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="login-password" [(ngModel)]="user.password">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.password"><br />
    {{ error }}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <span *ngFor="let error of _userService.errors.non_field_errors">{{ error }}<br /></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="_userService.token">
  <div class="col-sm-12">You are logged in as {{ _userService.username }}.<br />
    Token Expires: {{ _userService.token_expires }}<br />
    <button (click)="refreshToken()" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh Token</button>
    <button (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</button>
  </div>
</div>
<!--      
<h2 class="mt-3">Devices</h2>
<div *ngFor="let device of devices">
      <div class="row mb-3">
          <label class="col-md-2">Owner:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2 mb-1">{{ device.owner }}</div>
          <label class="col-md-2">Brand:</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">{{ device.brand }}</div>
          <div class="col-md-12">{{ device.name }}</div>
      </div>
</div>-->
```

App.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DevicePostService} from './device_post.service';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  /**
   * An object representing the user for the login form
   */
  public user: any;
  public devices;
  public new_device: any;

  constructor(private _devicePostService: DevicePostService, private _userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDevices();
    this.new_device = {};
    this.user = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  getDevices() {
      this._devicePostService.list().subscribe(
          data => {
              this.devices = data;
          },
          err => console.error(err),
          () => console.log('done loading devices')
      )
  }

  updateDevice () {
      this._devicePostService.create(this.new_device, this.user.token).subscribe(
      data => {
          this.getDevices();
          return true;
      },
          error => {
              console.error('Error saving!');
              return throwError(error);
          }
      );
  }

  login() {
    this._userService.login({'username': this.user.username, 'password': this.user.password});
  }

  refreshToken() {
    this._userService.refreshToken();
  }

  logout() {
    this._userService.logout();
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you provide `DevicePostService` in your NgModule?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a basic syntax error in your template

```
<button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button
```

should be

```
<button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
```

(note the final '>' character)